# Using twisted pair with Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino, noise, ethernet, cables, crosstalk

I have done a previous project where I used an Arduino Mega to control a Three-phase industrial metal pattern scrolling machine (bender), and I faced many problems with noise voltage spikes being read as interrupts on Arduino pins.

I am now doing another project of similar requirements but I am looking into using Cat5e twisted pair for signal transfer:

- (Mega-> Opto-isolated Relay Board)
- (Limit switches board->Mega)
- (Mega<->Keypad)

I am also planning on keeping the signal wires as far off from power wires and boards as possible.

Of course, differential mode is not feasible in this case, but I was thinking of connecting all the white pairs to GND in an attempt to reduce noise and cross-talk.

Has anyone tried anything similar?

The machine is not well grounded, so I do not know if a shielded cable will give me better results or not.
I am still doing my research before I start buying cables and terminals and it becomes more expensive to fix problems.

Any plausible suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What is your question? This is a question and answer site, discussions are discouraged unless you're in a chat room.

Comment: Has anyone used twisted pair cable with the white wires grounded? And what were the results?

Comment: results will be somewhat inferior to coax, Rami. Although it is more difficult, take advantage of the *balance* offered by floating twisted pairs. Drive each one with equal and opposite signals. Use a balanced receiver.

Comment: Please ask a question, for help on questions see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have dealt with noise and spikes on industrial equipment that was problematic even with opto-isolated I/O points. First off, are you running these wires directly from the I/O pins around the machine? If so, this is what needs to be addressed. Tell us what these pins are connected to such as relays, analog points, etc. From there, we can then assist you in figuring out what to do.

Some anecdote:

I was rebuilding an in house laser welding workstation with a new continuous wave laser with opto-isolated I/O. The machine also had a few big solenoids for shield gas and an air knife which blew spatter and smoke/vapors away from the protective cover glass of the laser head. Every time the air solenoid was shut off, the laser beam would pulse. Even though I had a flyback protection diode and emf filtering, that big solenoid coil was a real emf problem. I fixed it by doing two things. First I put the solenoids on their own power supply and electrically isolated the two DC systems. I then physically separated the wiring and moved the solenoid wiring and relays to another location away from the sensitive I/O wiring from the CNC controller. Worked perfectly.

Another story was a stepper motion system was false triggering I/O points from the PWM noise induced on the I/O wires from being in close proximity to the motor wires. Since the motors were in a vacuum chamber with only one common feed through for all wiring, I couldn't shield or isolate the wiring. I put a scope on the line and looked at my noise frequency and sized appropriate filter capacitors. The I/O voltage was 24VDC so I loaded the I/O wiring with 2.7k 1/2 W resistors along with the capacitors. That again solved my noise issues.

Comment: I have 2 8-channel relay boards I made that are opto-isolated. The relays operate at 12V and are used to switch 24V pneumatic valves (double and single acting). I will try to keep the valve control island as far as possible because I imagine the solenoids can cause trouble.

I also have a matrix keypad in this project as I did in the previous one. In the previous project, the keypad lines sometimes gave unexpected readings due to switching contractors and relays.

Comment: I want to try and make an opto-isolated board with filter capacitors for the limit switches I will be reading (around 10).

Comment: One more thing, how does loading the line help?

Comment: @Rami Are those solenoids equipped with DIN style connections? If so, do the DIN connectors have internal fly-back protection? The ideal location for fly-back protection is as close to the coil as possible. Remote fly-back protection still allows the current pulse to travel along the wires and induce currents in adjacent wires. I am actually building a relay box for a new laser workstation as I'm typing this and I am using DIN cables from Murr Elektronik with internal fly-back protection. They can be purchased from Automation Direct.

Comment: @Rami The opto-isolated I/O used very sensitive opto-isolators with a high current transfer ratio and a somewhat high input impedance. The motors PWM noise induced enough current on those wires to actually light the opto-isolator diode enough to trigger an input. Loading the input further with the 2.7k resistors ensured that any small currents from noise would be effectively "shorted out" and prevented from reaching the opto's. The resistor goes in parallel with the input as well as the capacitor for AC noise.

Comment: Good to know. My solenoids do not seem to have any fly-back protection. The solenoids operate at 24V and use 50-100mA I think. What kind of fly-back protection do you suggest? Is a 50V diode with 200-500mA forward current enough?

Comment: @Rami Standard 50V/1A 1n4001 are fine for protection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find doing this will give little benefit to you. This is because you are not creating a faraday's cage around your signal wire so EMI can still be induced in your wire.

You should either create a proper differential pair at the point of the relay or you should use a shielded cable that's correctly grounded on both ends. In preference you would do both

For most applications you'll find that a single ended shielded wire will be sufficient